# Arbitrary port number while connection being established

Tags: corda

Corda Enterprise 3.2 couldn't connect to other node. Handshake timeout occurs while trying.

Our node is behind the firewall in DMZ.
In node.conf p2pAddress is set like this: externalIP:10006
But in logs I see some strange things:
External node is trying to connect to our node by internalIP:[some arbitrary port (45608 for example)]
Because of we can't open our node for all kind of traffic, connection fails.

Answer (score 0):

have you followed the Corda Firewall and Bridge documentation on how to run a node in a DMZ config?

https://docs.corda.r3.com/releases/3.0/corda-firewall.html

Comment: I use the simplest way- bridge inside node. My node located in DMZ, so I thought there shouldn't be a problem to connect between two nodes. Firewall in DMZ pass all traffic from any IP to ports in range 10000:10100. But accidentally I see in my log some arbitrary ports that firewall blocks as I understand